# How do I add a string to all existing elements in array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

If I have an array such as the following

```js
var a = ["a","b","c","d"];
```

How can I add onto the string of each item using a loop to make the result return as so?

```
["i am a", "i am b", "i am c", "i am d"]
```

Comment: a `for` loop would do the trick

Comment: String concatenation in JavaScript is done with the `+` operator.

Comment: Just use a for loop and concatenate `array[counter] = "i am" + array[counter];` for each element.

Comment: @brso05 That is exactly what I was looking for! thank you! If you post it as an answer I can go ahead and accept it

Comment: @EpicSartorius your welcome glad I could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
["a","b","c","d"].map(function(e) { return "I am " + e });
```

or the full code would be (thanks mplungjan!)

```
var a = ["a","b","c","d"];
a = a.map(function(e) { return "I am " + e });
```

Comment: You mean `var arr = ["a","b","c","d"];

arr = arr.map(function(e) { return "I am " + e });` right?

Comment: I assumed OP would be able to figure out the rest :-). Have updated the answer. Cheers and thanks! (for the edit and the comment)

Comment: I definitely would assume he wasn't seeing he could not use "array, for loop and add" to find the answer on his own

Comment: I have been searching forever and still unable to get it to work... I am trying to do it with a loop though as opposed to using `a.map`

Comment: @EpicSartorius - `var a = ["a","b","c","d"]; for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) a[i] = "I am " + a[i];` like brso05 suggested. You might want to ask him to post it as an answer so that you can accept. Cheers!

Comment: @potatopeelings Cheers! Thanks for your help too!